# 'The node is not in a connected state' error when trying to execute OP_RETURN transaction with NBitcoin

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, transactions, bitcoin

This is my first time trying out the [NBitcoin](https://github.com/MetacoSA/NBitcoin) library to create a transaction. I am trying to create an `OP_RETURN` transaction, but every time I try to execute the `Version Handshake` with the node I get the error: `The node is not in a connected state`.

This is self explanatory, but I've tried a number of what are considered reliable nodes.

I guess this is a two part question:

1. When attempting an `OP_RETURN` transaction in NBitcoin, is it necessary to add the miner fees into the TransactionBuilder manually?
2. Is there a way to use `Node.Connect` so it will just search for available nodes, rather than specifying a specific node?

Heres my code, which is in a .NET MVC4 Controller Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult NewTransaction(string hash)
{
        var paymentSecret = new BitcoinSecret("//Private Key");
        var message = hash;
        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
        var blockr = new BlockrTransactionRepository();
        var fundingTransaction = blockr.Get("60db94bfb43dd0d98ba7fdfbbg4f29a850f7s5ea7d79a32c4r954096f2945b04");
        var payment = new Transaction();

        payment.Inputs.Add(new TxIn()
        {
            PrevOut = new OutPoint(fundingTransaction.GetHash(), 1)
        });

        payment.Outputs.Add(new TxOut()
        {
            Value = Money.Zero,
            ScriptPubKey = TxNullDataTemplate.Instance.GenerateScriptPubKey(bytes)
        });

        payment.Inputs[0].ScriptSig = paymentSecret.ScriptPubKey;
        payment.Sign(paymentSecret, false);

        using (var node = Node.Connect(Network.Main, "212.47.228.216", new NodeConnectionParameters()
        {
            IsTrusted = true,
            IsRelay = false
        }))
        {
            // Always fails on the handshake
            node.VersionHandshake();
            node.SendMessage(new InvPayload(InventoryType.MSG_TX, payment.GetHash()));
            node.SendMessage(new TxPayload(payment));
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
        return View("Index");
}
```

**EDIT**

I tried to actually use the `TransactionBuilder`, but still came up with the same error. This time I am actually setting the fee amount. I am also using a different node and specifying the port. Here is the attempt:

```
var paymentSecret = new BitcoinSecret("//Private Key");
var message = hash;
var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

var funding = new Transaction()
{
    Outputs =
    {
        new TxOut("0.01", paymentSecret.GetAddress())
    }
};

var coins = funding
                .Outputs
                .Select((o, i) => new Coin(new OutPoint(funding.GetHash(), i), o))
                .ToArray();

var txBuilder = new TransactionBuilder();
var tx = txBuilder
            .AddCoins(coins)
            .AddKeys(paymentSecret.PrivateKey)
            .Send(TxNullDataTemplate.Instance.GenerateScriptPubKey(bytes), Money.Zero)
            .SendFees("0.00001")
            .SetChange(paymentSecret.PubKey)
            .BuildTransaction(true);

txBuilder.Verify(tx);

using (var node = Node.Connect(Network.Main, "74.124.62.108:8333", new NodeConnectionParameters()
{
    IsTrusted = true,
    IsRelay = false
}))
{
    node.VersionHandshake();
    node.SendMessage(new InvPayload(InventoryType.MSG_TX, tx.GetHash()));
    node.SendMessage(new TxPayload(tx));
    Thread.Sleep(500);
 }
```

Could anyone help out. There is a lack of documentation specifying how to conduct an `OP_RETURN` transaction. Thanks.